# Linux undefined symbol _mkdir in the .so file of swmm5 python package

Tags: python, linux

I am new to python and Linux. I installed swmm5 package in Linux by downloading the source SWMM5-5.1.0.102.zip:

`python setup.py install`

Before typing the previous syntax to install swmm5, I have unquoted `#define CLE` and deleted `#include <direct.h>` in the file swmm5.c, otherwise the installation won't succeed.

Then I tried to test the swmm5 package and get the following error:

```
from swmm5.swmm5tools import SWMM5Simulation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pyangac/Py_libs/lib64/python/SWMM5-5.1.0.102-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/swmm5/swmm5tools.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import swmm5
  File "/home/pyangac/Py_libs/lib64/python/SWMM5-5.1.0.102-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/swmm5/swmm5.py", line 28, in <module>
    _swmm5 = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/pyangac/Py_libs/lib64/python/SWMM5-5.1.0.102-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/swmm5/swmm5.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _swmm5
ImportError: /home/pyangac/Py_libs/lib64/python/SWMM5-5.1.0.102-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_swmm5.so: undefined symbol: _mkdir
```

I have also installed the swmm5 package in Window, and the similar testing process gets no error.

Is there anyone understand what's going on and what should I do to use the swmm5 package in Linux? Thanks.

Comment: did you try 'pip install SWMM5'?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did. Actually, it turns out that it's the compatibility problem of the SWMM5 C code of version 5.1.008. I replaced the swmm5/swmm5 folder with the newest release 5.1.012 and now it works fine.